# Script para testear el correcto funcionamiento de Fopen y Curl

Tags: php

necesito ayuda para obtener un script para realizar el chequeo de correcto funcionamiento de Fopen y Curl.

Este es un problema el cual no tengo conocimiento para chequearlo si esta en funcionamiento, pese a que no tengo un total control sobre los sistemas del hosting.

Es un punto a presentar, pese a que cuando necesitamos realizar un diagnostico al vuelo no es posible realizar un seguimiento del problema el cual no se resolvería.

Comment: Podrías agregar a tu pregunta lo que haz intentado y que error te sale? Gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP te ofrece varias maneras de llevar a cabo tu objetivo:

**[`function-exists`](http://php.net/function-exists)**

```
if (function_exists('curl_init') !== false) {
  echo "CURL funcional";
} else {
  echo "CURL no funcional";
}
```

**[`get_loaded_extensions`](http://php.net/get_loaded_extensions)**

```
if (in_array('curl', get_loaded_extensions()) !== false) {
  echo "CURL cargado";
} else {
  echo "CURL no cargado";
}
```